# Redirecting naked domain to a social profile

Tags: seo, redirects, subdomain, social-media

What is the best practice for SEO?   I'm thinking about moving my blog to `blog.example.com` and having `example.com` redirection to my Instagram account.

Is it a good/bad idea? How can it affect my SEO ranking? Is it discouraged to do so? Do you have any insights about it or any advice?

Will it be better to have `example.com` redirect to `blog.example.com`?

Currently, my blog is hosted on the Hashnode (https://blog.cyberethical.me) - but they allow setting a custom domain. For that, I have to make changes to in my DNS settings - it is suggested to use the subdomain for that (because my provider does not support CNAME flattening).

So if I'm going to use a subdomain `blog.example.com` I want to make use of the root `example.com`. As I'm an active on IG and have some presence there, I'm wondering what is the best from the technical/SEO point of view.

Comment: You did not state the reason why you would want to do this. You want your Instagram to be too result for your old blog?

Comment: Your blog is currently hosted on your naked domain?   If so, what are you planning to do with deep URLs to your blog like `example.com/some-blog-post`?

Comment: I've added a bit of clarification.
Also @StephenOstermiller, I'm considering using relative URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend redirecting your naked domain to your Instagram profile, but not for SEO reasons.

For SEO it probably won't won't make any difference.   Search engines will happily index and rank your blog on the blog subdomain.  Since you have never had content on your naked domain, there is no need to implement redirects for search engines.  Search engines need the redirects when the content used to be hosted there and has moved.

Redirecting your naked domain to Instagram would not be good user experience for users that remember your domain name from reading your blog and try to type in your naked domain name trying to get back to your blog.  Instead they will get redirected to Instagram.   From Instagram, there will be no easy way to get to your blog.

The best practice is to run your blog on a subdomain, redirect the naked domain to that subdomain, and have links in your blog to your social media accounts.

If your provider does not support CNAME flattening (also known as ANAME, ALIAS records), I would recommend migrating to a DNS host that does support them.  Most big DNS hosts now support them.   It is usually possible to change your DNS host without changing your DNS registrar or your web host.   To do so:

1. Sign up for DNS hosting with a company that supports the features you want.
2. Replicate all your DNS records at your new DNS host.
3. At your domain registrar, change your NS records to point to your new DNS host.

At that point you will be able to use CNAME flattening at your new DNS host while you website is still hosted exactly like it is today.

Comment: Thanks, that's the approach I've chosen - to run the blog under `blog.example.com` and have `example.com` -> `blog.example.com` redirection.
About moving to other hosts - I think for now I will keep it as it is (for sake of simplicity).